# replace `_` with `-` in a string

Tags: c#

I have to replace `_` to `-` in the mail id in the specific case,trying with Index methods but not getting the proper identification.

Below is the actual case.

```
Mail id : abc@bc_cd_fd@gmail.com ( It's wrong as per my requiremnt)
```

I would like to replace this in the below format.

```
Required format :abc@bc-cd-fd@gmail.com
```

Tried in the below format

```
 string correctString = errString.Replace("_", "-");
```

but I have to do this after @ only.

Thanks in advance for your timely help.

Comment: find the part after the `@` (use `String.Split` or `IndexOf`) and do the same

Comment: You could Split the String. Or you could use Regular Expressions.

Comment: Tried it on my end and its working fine...

Comment: @JackFrost That's only because his example didn't have an underscore anywhere *but* after the @ symbol.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer - Oh. I see. I get it now. Well, he finds his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform replacement on text after the '@' sign, you first need isolate that part of the string. You can do this by using the `Split` method to split the string into two parts -- the part before, and the part after the '@' sign and running the replace only on the second portion:

```
public string FixEmail(String email) {
    var parts = email.Split('@');
    return parts[0] + "@" + parts[1].Replace("_", "-");
}

// ... snip ...

FixEmail("ab-c_d@12_34.com").Dump();
```

If you have multiple '@' signs in your email, you could try running the replace only on the last portion, and joining together the first parts:

```
public string FixEmail(String email) {
    var parts = email.Split('@');
    parts[parts.Length - 1] = parts[parts.Length - 1].Replace("_", "-");
    return String.Join("@", parts);
}
```

Comment: It could have more parts than 2.

Answer (score 1):

Some indexed linq will make it fast and easy:

```
var result = string.Join("@", "aaa_a@_a_".Split('@').ToList().
                             Select((s, i) => i > 0 ? s.Replace('_', '-') : s).
                             ToArray());

//returns aaa_a@-a-
```

Comment: :I am using 2.0,LinQ i can't use here, but thanks for your responce, i will try this one also.